# GetCurrentDirectory does not really return the path of the executable file

Tags: c++, service, windows-services

I am coding a program as service using c++, when I test it as a normal program, the function `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the correct path. But when I try to install my program as service, `GetCurrentDirectory` returns `C:\Windows\System32` instead of the path of the executable.

How can I get the path of my executable file in a way that will work for a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directory for Windows services is always `%WINDIR%\System32`.

To get directory, where your executable resides, simply call [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx) with NULL for `hModule` argument, and manually strip executable name.

Comment: Thank you, It Work

Answer (score 1):

Because `%WinDir%\System32` is the default working directory for a 32/64 bit Windows service (`%WinDir%\SysWOW64` for 32 bit services on 64 bit Windows).

You may set working directory of your service to something else, see also [Windows Service: Can I configure the current working directory?](https://serverfault.com/q/114238) or - better - do not rely in your code about working directory. Few options:

- Read it from registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>\ImagePath`.
- Use WMI to enumerate services (if you really want to...)
- Use `GetModuleFileName()`. It's easy to use but be careful: it has some tricky behavior with WOW64, some virtualization environments and for `svcshot` hosted services (it's *little bit* old but you may want to read [this article](http://www.openrce.org/blog/view/902/Dissecting_Windows_XP_Svchost_Internals_:_Traversing_Core_Parameters).)
- Use `QueryServiceConfig()`.

What I'd suggest:

- Save/load your data in a shared known folder, for example for Common Application Data: `SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath)`.