# Poco's Path current() is not returning the current working directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file, filesystems, poco-libraries

I am trying to get the current working directory of the C++ program using Poco::Path::current(). It is working fine and gives the correct path when I run the program as normal or "Run As Administrator". But the problem occurs when run the program using "Run Elevated". The function will return "C:\WINDOWS\system32" instead of the working directory. I tried to find the solutions but so far there is none for Poco library. I found a similar problem at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841907/getcurrentdirectory-does-not-really-return-the-path-of-the-executable-file) but it is using GetModuleFileName which is for Windows only. I need to deploy the program in different OS like linux and Poco library takes care of that. Is there another way to get the real working directory using Poco library when running the program as elevated or I need to check if is windows, use GetModuleFileName method and else just use Poco's current() function?

Comment: What happens if you start an elevated command prompt, change to the directory you want, and then run your program?  I believe that elevated programs use `c:\windows\system32` as their working directory by default.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 if I do this, it will return the correct working directory

Comment: That's what I'm asking you.  It's a test.  It shouldn't take more than a minute to try.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 I did this "start an elevated command prompt, change to the directory you want, and then run your program" and the result is >> it will return the correct working directory

Comment: Are you looking for the current working dir?  Or for the dir of the executable?  As @Tumbleweed53 said, the current working dir for elevated cmd prompts is `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.  This is how Windows works, not Poco.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Poco::Application` as your base class for your main, then you can use the `Poco::Application::commandPath()` function.

If not, you can do something similar to what Poco does in `Poco::Application::getApplicationPath()`.